# Access a database value on a ListView

Tags: android, database

I have a database of webpages like this:

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
    public interface ThreadDatabase extends BaseColumns {
    String TABLE_NAME = "Threads";
    String TITLE = "Title";
    String DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    String URL = "Url";
    String[] COLUMNS = new String[] { _ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, URL };
}
```

And a Listview in my Activity with a SimpleCursorAdapter that displays Title and Descripton in every row.

```
Cursor c = dbhelper.getDatabase();
setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, new String[] {
                    ThreadDatabase.TITLE, ThreadDatabase.DESCRIPTION },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, })
```

How could I redefine onListItemClick method so that when I click on the item the right url is opened?

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ???Missing part???
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your activity extends ListActivity. If so, in onListItemClick(), all you need to do is:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Cursor item = (Cursor)getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to your SimpleCursorAdapter so initialize it to a field.

Assuming you have a field mAdapter, you can get the cursor like this:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);    

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope that helps.